# Random permutation of numbers in MATLAB with weights

Tags: matlab, random, markov-chains

How to randomize the numbers in a vector `a`, with weights assigned in such a way that I can control what numbers 'follow' other numbers?

Let's say:

```
a = [ 1 2 3 4]
```

I would like to obtain something like this:

```
1 2 1 3 4 2 1 4 3 4 1 3 4 1 ....
```

My aim is to create a longer vector (including these numbers ranging from 1 to 4, permuted), while adding weights:

- 1 → 2, 2 → 1 (a 2 following a 1 in the vector and vice versa) in 1/3 of cases
- 3 → 4, 4 → 1 (a 3 following a 4 in the vector and vice versa) in 1/3 of cases
- All other possible transitions, 1/3 of cases

I managed to obtain a longer vector with these numbers permuted, but I do not know how to apply these weights/rules.

Comment: Walking on a [markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain)?

Comment: This question is quite related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161927

Comment: The description of the problem *all other possible transitions 1/3* is mathematically contradictory. Do you mean: *All other possible transitions: 1/3 * 2/3 = 2/9?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this transition matrix of your Markov chain:

```
M = 1/9*[2, 3, 2, 2; ...
         3, 2, 2, 2; ...
         2, 2, 2, 3; ...
         3, 2, 2, 2];
```

with the following algorithm:

```
function realizations = realizeMarkovChain(M, start, numSteps)
%// Generates realization of Markov chain given by transition matrix M.
%// The probabilities of going from state i to a different state are given
%// by the rows M(i,:) of the transition matrix
currentPosition = start;
cdf = cumsum(M,2);
realizations = zeros(1, numSteps);

for i = 1:numSteps
   currentPosition = find(rand < cdf(currentPosition,:), 1, 'first');
   realizations(i) = currentPosition;
end
```